# Save as query is disabled in application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

Trying to save my kql in application insight but save as query is disabled. Im contributor in the application insight (workspace based). What need to change?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the **`Save as Query`**/**`Save as function`** in Logs Panel, need to be **scope** selected into the specific resource like Subscription Level, Resource Group Level, Resource (Function App, Web App, Application Insights, etc.) Level.

Set **Scope** to **Resource Group** Level, only **`Save As Query`** Option is enabled:

[image]

As I did set **Scope** to **Application Insights** Resource Level, then I got **both options** like **`Save As Query`** and **`Save As Function`**:

[image]

Refer to the [Limitations in Azure Portal when scoped to a resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/scope#limitations-when-scoped-to-a-resource) provided by Microsoft.